# any handy tools for debug and modify flex style

Tags: apache-flex

each time I want to modify the style in Flex, I have to change the style and compile, if there is tool for dynamic change the style just like firebug for Html

Comment: for default controls you could use Flex Style explorer http://examples.adobe.com/flex2/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex2StyleExplorer.html

Answer (score 2):

[SWFWire Debugger](http://www.swfwire.com/debugger) has an inspect feature like Firebug, and the ability to modify any property.  There is nothing specific to Flex styles, though.

Edit:
The latest version has a Styles tab that lets you modify common styles.

Answer (score 1):

[Flex-Spy](http://code.google.com/p/fxspy/)

> Flex-Spy is a simple tool that can be
>   used to inspect, monitor, and
>   dynamically change most properties and
>   styles of the visual components in
>   your Flex application.